# AWS Glue Job - Job Bookmark - Incremental daily extraction from RDS to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm building up/developing a serveless pipeline using AWS Glue.

**Context**: I'm extracting data from RDS AWS Postgres instance. This instance is a productive database of a mobile app (OLTP).

**Goal**: Extract historical and incremental data. Setting up Glue PySpark jobs in order to extract not only the historical data but also the "daily deltas". Write parquet files on S3 bucket daily folders. Cap writing of parquet files up to 128MB.

**Up to now**: I've already scheduled a Crawler, it updates and map tables and schema, weekly.

Most of the RDS tables have these 3 fields:

"id" "created_at" "updated_at"

The app's backend inserts new rows in the RDS (*"created_at" == "updated_at"*), but also **updates** (not changing the ID) previously inserted rows (*so "created_at" < "updated_at"*)

On the first job run with bookmark enabled, it will grab the historical data, on the second run (let's say T+1), will the bookmark catch the updated rows?

Besides this, is there any other consideration or advice you consider worth sharing?

Will the following code meet my requirements?

```
import sys
import datetime
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "128M")


# Script generated for node e_transaction_table
e_transaction_table_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="paretopago",
    table_name="paretopago_public_transactions",
    transformation_ctx="e_transaction_table_node1",
    additional_options= {"jobBookmarkKeys" : ["id", "updated_at"], "jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder":"asc"})

current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
output_path = f"s3://appa-aws-glue-data/transactions/{args['JOB_NAME']}/{current_datetime}/"

# Script generated for node l_transaction_table
l_transaction_table_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=e_transaction_table_node1,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="glueparquet",
    connection_options={"path": output_path, "partitionKeys": []},
    format_options={"compression": "snappy"},
    transformation_ctx="l_transaction_table_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For your specific goal, I'd suggest using Spark dataframe (without any Glue libraries), which can make your code more portable (e.g., can run on any Spark platform such as EMR serverless).

The read section should look like below. Note that you'll have to read the `max_datetime` from the target table first.

```py
sql_query = f"select * from {source_table} where {delta_col_name} > '{max_datetime}"

jdbc_df = (spark.read.format("jdbc")
           .option("url", jdbcUrl)
           .option("user", secret["username"])
           .option("password", secret["password"])
           .option("query", sql_query)
           .load()
           )
```

The write section should be like this. Note that you'll have to add the `year`, `month`, and `day` columns in the transformation phase.

```py
final_df.write.mode("append") \
    .option("maxRecordsPerFile", estimated_num_of_records_close_to_128mb) \
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day") \
    .parquet(output_path, compression="snappy")
```